# Resultados vindo repetidos do banco de dados

Tags: php

Estou criando um *quiz*, mas como faço para que as perguntas não se repitam?

```
// Executa uma consulta que pega as questoes
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `questoess` WHERE IdPergunta=' .rand(1,4);
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while ($dados = $query->fetch_array()) {
        echo ' ' . $dados['Pergunta'] . '<br><br>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="a" />'. 'AlternativaA: ' . $dados['AlternativaA'] . '<br>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="b" />'. 'AlternativaB: ' . $dados['AlternativaB'] . '<br>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="c" />'. 'AlternativaC: ' . $dados['AlternativaC'] . '<br>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="d" />'. 'AlternativaD: ' . $dados['AlternativaD'] . '<br>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="e" />'. 'AlternativaE: ' . $dados['AlternativaE'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Bem-vinda, você pode começar fazendo [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e para obter respostas que solucionem sua dúvida / problema leia [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A ideia é mostrar todas as perguntas em ordem aleatória? Este código que você colocou está sendo executado dentro de um laço? Pois parece-me que ele seleciona apenas uma pergunta por vez e não teria como ficar repetida.

Comment: coloca a impressão da pergunta antes do while, pegando somente o conteúdo da primeira linha, e então no while você imprime as alternativas. Está se repetindo porque em cada linha você tem a alternativa e a pergunta... a pergunta ficando dentro do while, será impressa também

Answer (score 3):

Da forma que está a fazer, com `rand(1,4)` pelo php:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `questoess` WHERE IdPergunta=' .rand(1,4);
```

Terá que fazer múltiplas consultas ao banco de dados e teria que armazenar os ids que já tinham saído para não os repetir, complicando drasticamente o algoritmo.

Bastante mais simples será ordenar aleatoriamente na consulta e extrair a quantidade de resultados que pretende, utilizando `rand()` e `LIMIT`:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `questoess` order by rand() LIMIT 5';
```

Neste ultimo exemplo obtêm diretamente `5` questões do banco de dados, de forma aleatória, restando apenas utiliza-las.

Nota: Confirme se o nome da tabela está correto (`questoess`) pois em termos de ortografia tem um `s` a mais